# javascript type conversion arrays to string,toString not achieve

Tags: javascript

[1,2].toString() is "1,2",toString() cannot achieve

how to turn arrays[1,2] into string "[1,2]"

var a=[1,2,3]
var b=a.toString()

b="1,2,3"

Comment: Thank you for your instructions

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you.

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var b=a.toString();
b = '"'+b+'"';
alert(b);
```

Comment: JSON.stringify() can accomplish